# AngularJS: How to prevent recursive templating from looping forever

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've written a set of code which, when bound to an object, will display the key and value of every property in that object.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="object-displayer">
   <div ng-if="recurrable(value)">
     <span class="recurrable">
       <span class="key">{{key}}</span>
       (<span class="type" ng-bind="type(value)"></span>)
     </span>
     <ul class="indent">
       <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in value track by $index" ng-include="'object-displayer'"></li>
     </ul>
   </div>

   <div ng-if="!recurrable(value)">
     <span class="primitive">
       <span class="key">{{key}}</span> (<span class="type" ng-bind="type(value)"></span>): <span class="value">{{value}}</span>
     </span>
   </div>
</script>
```

And within the controller:

```
$scope.recurrable = function (value) {
  return typeof value === 'object';
}

$scope.type = function (value) {
  return typeof value;
}
```

jsbin: (https://jsbin.com/xusiteluwi/1/edit?html,js,output)

This works great when your nested objects create a simple tree structure. But it throws an exception when you create a loop: if one of your properties references any object upstream, it will display until the digest limit is reached (usually 10).

Now here's my question. Is there some way in angular controller/templating to ng-if whether an object has already been shown, thus catching any loops and displaying only a single iteration?

Bonus points if you can come up with a solution that will apply globally in the graph, or a solution that will only track the current branch.

Answer (score 0):

Start with an empty visitedReferences.

Each time you encounter any reference (object) check if it is in the visitedReferences and if so don't follow this reference, otherwise add it to the visitedReferences.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Where do I initiate this hash? How do I update it when it's 'encountered' in the template code?

Comment: Hey :). First of all even in your tempate you can update it using 'ng-init' (even it is not best practice, but you can). If you want me to try to code for you, please reduce your code js+html (I mean leave just what is essential) and put it working code on https://jsbin.com/. In general you will get much more help from the users here if you put it jsbin/jsfiddle/plnkr or any other :)

Comment: https://jsbin.com/xusiteluwi/1/edit?html,js,output

As an example without a loop, and an example with a loop:

https://jsbin.com/wuqaxexina/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: In your case just prepare the data in advance: https://jsbin.com/holowuvupa/edit?html,js,output  But if you have your own reasons not to perform the data in advance then you can put this logic in a $scope method and to call it from your template.

Answer (score 0):

Hope Help You!

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .controller('RecursiveCtrl', function($scope) {
    var vm = $scope;
    
    vm.data = {
      a: 'Hello',
      b: {
        c: 'World'
      }
    };
  
    vm.isRecursive = function(value) {
      return angular.isObject.call(this, value);
    };
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<article data-ng-app="test">


  <div data-ng-controller="RecursiveCtrl">
  
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl-recursive">

      <div ng-switch="isRecursive(value)">
      
      <div ng-switch-when="false" >
        <strong ng-bind="prop"></strong>: <span ng-bind="value"></span>
      </div>
  
        <div ng-switch-when="true">
           <ol>
            <li ng-repeat="(prop, value) in value" ng-include="'tpl-recursive'">
            </li>  
          </ol>
        </div>      
      </div>


    </script>
  


    <ol>
      <li ng-repeat="(prop, value) in data" ng-include="'tpl-recursive'"></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  
</article>
```